# Need to send an email if particular entry is missing from SVN commit message

Tags: email, svn, message, missing-symbols

I need to send an email if my SVN commit message is missing from particular entries.

My SVN commit message would be like:

Key1 : Value1

Key2 : Value2

Key3 : Value3

Key4 : Value4

Key5 : Value5

If a developer checks the code without Value1 or Value2, the developer should get and auto-generated mail. I am using Jenkins as our build system but Jenkins doesn't provide this functionality. I would have to use some customized Emailer for this.
Please suggest a way to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a *hook*. [svn hook link](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) demonstrates one. Google it.

Comment: Thanks Heal for the response. Is there any way to do this using shell script ?

Comment: The hook runs a script - see the example that uses python. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.start-commit.html would be a good starting point